# ¿Cómo regresar un valor de tipo string?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Cómo le hago para que una función me regrese el valor de **usuario** porque si le dejo `ToInt32` me regresa un número.
Si le Pongo `ToString`me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la función es el siguiente:

```
 Public Function Tecnico() As Integer
    Dim con As String
    con = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=NovariantNPI;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = con
    Dim query As New SqlCommand("select Usuario from Usuarios where Usuario = '" & My.Forms.Login.UsernameTextBox.Text & "'", cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    Return Convert.ToString(query.ExecuteNonQuery)
End Function
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ExecuteScalar sólo devuelve valores numéricos, por lo cual, para devolver un valor texto deberás crear un DataReader, por ejemplo, así:

```
Public Function Tecnico() As String
    Dim con As String
    con = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=NovariantNPI;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = con
    Dim query As New SqlCommand("select Usuario from Usuarios where Usuario = '" & My.Forms.Login.UsernameTextBox.Text & "'", cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim Consulta As SqlDataReader
    Consulta = query.ExecuteReader()
    Dim res As String = Nothing
    If Consulta.Read() Then res = Consulta(0)
    Consulta.Close()
    cnn.Close()
    Return res
End Function
```

Comment: me arroja `null`

Comment: ¿Puede ser que no exista el usuario que estás buscando?
Por otro lado, también te convendría cambiar la concatenación del where por parámetros, para evitar SQL Injection.

Comment: si existe ya execute el query en el sql y se me arroja un resultado. a no se que el TexBox este vacio.

Comment: el drConsulta de donde lo sacas?

Comment: @Giovanni imagino que se equivoco al copiarlo, pero solo borrale el dr y listo.

Comment: Es así, me quedó mal al copiarlo, pero ya lo corregí.  Saludos.

Comment: aun asi me arroja **NULL**

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te devuelve?

Comment: @GustavoCantero ningun error. solo que no regresa nada.

Comment: @Giovanni, seguro que probaste el código que puse yo?  Porque acabo de crear un proyecto para probarlo y me di cuenta que quedó mal una linea y me da un excepción.  Donde decía "Consulta(1)" debía ser "Consulta(0)".
Ahora funciona perfecto (lo probé en mi máquina).
Saludos.

Comment: @GustavoCantero si. no me da ninguna excepción. solo un warning que el resultado podria ser NULL. deja pruebo eso que comentas

Comment: @GustavoCantero ya lo solucione en el formulario Login limpiaba los texbox. quite esas lineas y listo.

Comment: Buenísimo, me alegro!

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que tu función retorne un String entonces te falta cambiar el tipo de dato de retorno a String en la cabecera de tu función, de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Function Tecnico() As String
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro, pero creo saber qué pasa.

```
Public Function Tecnico() As Integer
```

Eso devuelve un entero, debes colocarlo como:

```
Public Function Tecnico() As String
```

Cuando no le pones el toInt32, te regresa un número 1 o 0 dependiendo de si es true o false la conversión.